# Are Metro: Last Light and Metro: 2033 the same game, with updated graphics?

Tags: version-differences, metro-2033, metro-last-light

I'm thinking of buying Metro: Last Light, though from screenshots I have seen it looks the same as Metro 2033 simply with better graphics.

Are these two games basically the same or are there substantial differences between them?

Comment: Hello, Zanepain, I just wanted to let you know that if you found twobugs' answer useful, you should probably mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, Last Light is the sequel to 2033. There is a Metro 2033 Redux which features 2033 redone on Last Light's engine, as well as some other enhancements.

Comment: @Zanepain if two bugs' answer has helped you, you should mark it as the 'accepted' answer by clicking the checkmark under the vote count :). This awards both of you with some extra rep points :).